# Why isn't my DropdownButtonFormField showing the items?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this Dropdown:

```dart
DropdownButtonFormField(
  value: shipmentSelected,
  hint: Text(
    'choose one',
  ),
  onChanged: (value){
    shipmentSelected = value;
  }
  items: product.shipment.map((Shipment shipment) {
    return DropdownMenuItem(
      value: shipment.code,
      child: Text(
        shipment.code,
      ),
    );
  }).toList(),
)
```

But it doesn't show any item... just show the hintText. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a callback function to `onChanged` in the `DropdownButtonFormField` constructor. Update `shipmentSelected` and rebuild from this function like so:

```
onChanged: (value) {
  setState(() {
    shipmentSelected = value;
  });
},
```

Comment: See my update, it still not showing the items

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after the line `shipmentSelected = value`, if the code you share here is the code you're working with. That'll throw an error which will prevent your app from updating.

Comment: I miss it here, but the widget still with the same behaviour

Comment: Are you certain `product.shipment` contains shipments, and that these shipments all have a `code`? If you do, I think you need to post more code, there doesn't seem much wrong with the snippet that you've shared, so it must be something outside of it.

Comment: You're halfway there. The problem is you're not rebuilding the UI after setting the new value. I have updated the answer with the correct code.